# How to populate a TableView on Xcode playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I want to create an app on **Xcode playgrounds** that has a tableView which gets the data from a XML file. How can I do this?

My XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/ PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <array>
            <string>María Dolores Pilar</string>
            <string>11.327</string>
            <string>9.274</string>
            <string>7.554</string>
        </array>
    </array>
</plist>
```

It should be saved in a struct Person:

```
struct Person {
    var name:String
    var stones:Double
    var pounds:Double
    var ounces:Double
    var kilograms:Double {
        get {
            stones*6.35+pounds*0.4536+ounces*0.02835
        }
    }
}
```

And then populate the TableView with that information

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var list = [Person]()
    var selectedRowNumber:Int?
    
    var tableView:UITableView!

    var myConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint]!

    func addComponents() -> Void {
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

       self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 768)
        
        self.addComponents()
        self.setUpConstraints()
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(myConstraints)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

How can I populate the TableView programmatically in playgrounds?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The same way you do in an Xcode project. Right now you have not defined any `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: Your question is basically two questions in one: a) how to parse an XML file into a struct; b) how to populate a table view. Consider asking separate questions for that. The short answer for question b is implementing a UITableViewDataSource protocol which your view controller conforms to but does not implement any of its methods yet. When it comes to XML parsing, I definitely recommend searching on Stack Overflow first, there are plenty of questions related to this topic.

Comment: UPD: I've just noticed that your XML is not just any XML, it's a plist. Better search for PropertyListDecoder tutorials.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev The problem is, that after defininf the method to fill it, I still don't know how to populate it when adding the components to the view

Comment: You have to implement the methods of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol in order to fill the table with your data, as was suggested previously in the comments. If you're not yet familiar with it, take a look at [Filling a Table with Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/filling_a_table_with_data) documentation article.